# After restart of computer, Eclipse removed all projects in workspace?

Tags: eclipse, adt

I am using the latest Eclipse ADT, and I had to restart my computer using the power button. Before hard-resetting my computer, I properly closed Eclipse and waited for it to close. There were no other programs in the background besides my antivirus. 
When Windows 7 started back up, I re-opened Eclipse, only to find a blank workspace with none of my projects.

The actual source code is still present in the workspace folder, but I will have to manually import them again now. Why did Eclipse decide to randomly wipe my workspace?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply import all your projects again in the workspace.
Go to:

```
import   -->   import projects -->   
then select the projects you wanna bring back  --> then ok and done!
```